# Sending email in sandbox post copy

Tags: apex, email, user, deliverability, sandboxpostcopy

When I refresh a sandbox I have a class that runs to fix some things like email addresses and custom settings. I've also been asked to email the developer the new org ID so that their testing environments can stay connected.

The problem is when I refresh the sandbox, email deliverability defaults to "system email only", and I cannot switch it to "All Emails" until after logging in, which is well after the refreshpostcopy has run. This means I can't email as part of the refreshpostcopy.

Is there a way to set email deliverability to "all emails" in apex? If not is there another way to get the developer that information?

```
    String sysemail = [SELECT Email FROM User WHERE Email like 'myusername' LIMIT 1].email;

    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();
    sendTo.add('myemail@test.com');
    mail.setToAddresses(sendTo);
    mail.setSubject('Subject');
    mail.setPlainTextBody('New Sandbox ID is '+context.organizationId());
    mails.add(mail);
    Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
```

The error I get is `System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: NO_MASS_MAIL_PERMISSION, Single email is not enabled for your organization or profile.: []`

Comment: you could do a callout to something like slack or twilio (sms) if you use tools like these

Comment: I'll look into that thanks. We use slack. No idea what that entails though

Comment: It is pretty easy.  I did a trivial slack integration when Community user asked a question.  Worked almost immediately.

Answer (score 1):

When you create/refresh sandbox, Email Deliverability default to **System Email Only**. **System Email Only** allows us to send emails to users or reset passwords.You can run below class, when you create/refresh sandbox.
[image]

When you run below class then it will update all System Admin's user's email address and that will eventually send email to user.

```
global class SandboxPostRefresh_AC implements SandboxPostCopy { 

    global void runApexClass(SandboxContext context) { 

        System.debug(context.organizationId()); 

        System.debug(context.sandboxId()); 

        System.debug(context.sandboxName()); 

        run(); 

    } 

   global static void run() { 

   //List of all emails from the User object  

    List<User> userEmailList = [select Email from User where profile.name = ‘System Administrator’]; 

    for(User uc : userEmailList) 

    { 

        uc.Email = uc.Email.replace('=','@'); 

        //to remove appended domain 

        String addedPhrase = '@example.com'; 

        uc.Email = uc.Email.remove(addedPhrase); 

        userEmailList.add(uc); 

    } 

    if(userEmailList.size() > 0) 

    { 

         Update userEmailList; 

    } 

    } 
}
```

Comment: Hi sfdc. I've just clarified my question a little bit more. I have a version of that class that runs when my sandbox is refreshed and it works. But I can't send an email as part of the post refresh because the default deliverability settings.  I need to change the deliverability settings in apex

Comment: 'System Email Only' should allow emails to Users.You don't need to set it to 'All Emails'.Please check this link https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=emailadmin_deliverability.htm&type=5

Comment: System email only: Allows only automatically generated emails, such as new user and password reset emails. Especially useful for controlling email sent from sandboxes so that testing and development work doesn’t send test emails to your users. Newly created sandboxes default to System email only.

Comment: OOH okay I understand. I was currently hardcoding the email address, but I should just make it email the user I'm looking for directly. I understand now, thanks!

Comment: I'm still not able to send emails when referencing a user ID directly. I've added code to the question regarding the email construction.

Comment: @denvergreene When you refresh sandbox all users email address is appended by =@example.com and my code will fix email address of user and that will send email automatically to users.

Comment: I have a code that does that (I think it actually has .invalid at the end now). But I'm trying to send the org Id to a user, not just reset their email address.